# Adding new standard actions

Tags: delphi

I have compiled a vcl package, a collection of components which registered several 
actions in delphi 2009. Now, starting from these actions, i have created others
but, even if I register it, I cannot see them in Action Edit Dialog. How
I can add them?

Answer (score 5):

How did you register them?

This should work:

```
unit MyPackageReg;

interface

uses
  ActnList, MyActionUnit;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterActions('Category', [TMyActionType], nil);
end;

end.
```

Note the capital R in both Register declarations.

Now compile that package and install it.

Comment: yes. I did it but cannot see the category in the dialog. Should I compile the package again? I guess no...

Comment: Compiling alone is not enough. You have to intall the package to actually do the registering part.